# Could anyone explain the meaning of the following sentence

Tags: meaning

In my offer letter there is one section named "End of Contract". In this section there is one item which I don't understand clearly. This is as follows:

**Your service could be ended by giving thirty (30) days' notice or recompense one (1) month salary as replacement of notice.**

Q: Could anyone explain the meaning of this sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are unsure of the meaning of a legal document, you should definitely ask a lawyer before you sign it.

I am not a lawyer and not qualified to give legal advice (so please don't misconstrue my answer as such). I also don't have the full context of the document. Often in a contract several terms have very specific meanings which are defined early on in the document.

Despite all of the above, I'll tell you my best guess:
In order to terminate your contract (that is, fire you) the company has to give you 30 days notice before they stop paying you. They could either give you notice and have you continue working for 30 days, or they could fire you effective immediately, but they would still have to continue to pay you for the next month.

Answer (score 0):

...or fire you and give you the severance pay at that time, to avoid the possibility that you will cause retribution if they give you 30 days notice.